# How to detect if left mousebutton is being held down with SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I know how to use events to detect when the mouse button is pressed, however, how do detect if a mouse button is currently held down? Note I am not asking how to get it from an event.

I have not tried anything apart from `SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);` however it seems to only return the X and Y position of the mouse.

Comment: I think you mean "I know how I can use events to detect when the mouse button is pressed or released".

Comment: `SDL_GetMouseState` returns which buttons are pressed. There's [an example](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetMouseState) in the manual.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you! Can you post the answer so I can give you the green checkmark? This is a much easier method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SDL_GetMouseState()` returns the buttons that were pressed. Example:

```
if (SDL_GetMouseState(...) & SDL_BUTTON_LMASK)
    // Left button is pressed.
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding a state machine should do the trick.
If you detect a MB Down event (`SDL_PRESSED`), set a variable to hold that information for you, if you detect a MB Up event (`SDL_RELEASED`), reset the variable.
So reading the content of this variable would return the "held down" information.

Side info: Depending on the mouse you are using the button state may bounce between high and low state. If that is the case, add a samll (~1ms) delay.

Because i do not have SDL2 currently on my machine, i can not provide code.
Sorry for that.

In case you have trouble finding the SDL2 docu for this because they reworked their wiki, here is a link: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MouseButtonEvent

But let me know if this was helpful.